# ASP.NET GridView is not updating inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView that is bound to a SQL Data source.  I have put this inside an Update panel and want the contents to update at a specified interval.  The problem is that if i change the data in the database, the GridView does not update itself, i have to manually refresh the page to view the new data.

What else do I need to do to get a GridView to refresh itself?

```
<asp:Timer ID="RefreshTimer" runat="server" Interval="10000" 
    ontick="RefreshTimer_Tick">
</asp:Timer>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="quad1"><uc1:MyWidget ID="MyWidget1" runat="server" /></div>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call gridView.DataBind() on tick event

Answer (score 0):

Use a Timer like this:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="30000">
```

Follow this [Auto-refresh update panel sample](http://sanjevsharma.blogspot.com/2007/10/auto-refresh-update-panel-on-page-using.html) and should have no problem. Let me know if you do.